# Signature associate with an annotation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

How to know what kind of signature and annotation is expecting. For example:

org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener

Spring doc provide some samples. But how do I find the code that invoke the method and its expectation for the signature?

Answer (score 1):

> How to know what kind of signature and annotation is expecting.

There is no signature, you call the annotation with parameters, and it does what you ask him to do. The signature is provided by you on the method that you place the annotation on.

> But how do I find the code that invoke the method

Why would you want to do that? You can find the code on `github` such as for [@KafkaListener](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/KafkaListener.java) interface, but most of the time there is no need to.

If someone gives you a car, you just use it(assuming you know how to drive), there is no need to know how a car works internally, unless of course you are really interested, or you want to do a pull-request :)

Comment: You talk a lot for three words: I dont know

Comment: In fact I wasn't sure what compelled you to at all. I meant you can keep silent if you don't have the answer, I found it myself and pr to springboot to add what I need. But your reply surprised me.

Answer (score 1):

You can have whatever signature you want and the framework will attempt to do any necessary conversion.

Simplest is `listen(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record)` where you get the raw Kafka `ConsumerRecord`.

`listen(Foo foo)` will return the `record.value()` (assuming it's a `Foo` or can be converted to one).

Some more examples:

`listen(String value, @Headeer("someHeader") String header`

`listen(@Payload String value, @Headeer("someHeader") String header` - if you want to explicitly annotate for the value.

`listen(String value, Consumer<?, ?> consumer` - when you want to call the consumer yourself.

`listen(String value, Acknowledgnent ack)` - when using a MANUAL ack mode.